# How does the WifiAnalyzer app get WiFi scan results without requesting for GPS?

Tags: android, wifi

I thought that, in order to get Wifi scan results, you need to ask for coarse permissions and to activate GPS to get it working (from Android 6.0.)

But the thing is that I have just checked that on Android 7.0, WifiAnalyzer achieves this information without asking for GPS. How is this possible?

Comment: Well, you thought wrong. It isn't needed to have GPS active to find wifi. Case point: Disable GPS, disconnect from the wifi and turn it off and back on. Results show up even with disabled GPS, and connects without it.

Comment: Download the `.apk` file, decompile it and look at the source code. Then you have to find the code location, where the available WiFi networks get searched/received. I know, this could take some amount of time. But then you'll have a answer to your question.

Comment: It does. Scanresults from the wifi manager returns nothing if GPS is turned off. But in that app is different. In the an android 6.0 it asks to turn in location services, but not in 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now the only way to get the wifi scans without turning on the GPS is to set the app's

`targetSDKVersion` to 21 or lower.

This works regardless of the device's os being Lolipop or above.